# Auto code completion in GEdit and VIM, for C++

Tags: centos, vim, autocomplete, gedit

Being a Visual Studio fan, I am just wondering if I can have same feature in GEdit and VIM.

PS : I’m new to VIM and currently using CentOS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have that same auto code completion for C++ feature.

Both Gedit and Vim have facilities for extension through plug-ins. This allows you to write the completion, so you can have that feature in either of them.

You might want to spent some time looking if someone has not already done so.

Comment: Any suggestions for plug-ins ?

Comment: @deXter You should post that as a different question. For `vim` have a look at [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) or better the setup from https://github.com/xautjzd/dotvim